# What is the reason to select MinMaxScaler or Normalization?

Tags: lstm, normalization, scaling, normalize, data-preprocessing

I am working on LSTM model, and i saw different pre-processing for the similar data on the web. Can you please help me to understand difference between them and which one should i select:

**1) MinMaxScaler**

```
X_std = (X - X.min(axis=0)) / (X.max(axis=0) - X.min(axis=0))
X_scaled = X_std * (max - min) + min
```

**2) Normalized to the range of (0 to 1) by Eq.**

```
x=(Xi-Xmin)/(Xmax-Xmin)
```

**3) Normalize**

```
train_mean = train_df.mean()
train_std = train_df.std()

train_df = (train_df - train_mean) / train_std
val_df = (val_df - train_mean) / train_std
test_df = (test_df - train_mean) / train_std
```

**My dataset:** min value is 0 and max value is 1600.Almost one third of my dataset is zero. I do not have a negatif value.

thank you !

I tried minmaxscaler

Comment: what kind of data are you working with, is it sales data, 1/3 of your data is 0?

Comment: it's a time series energy dc power data.

Comment: i think normalized is center at 0 right? so min max can shrink your data to 0-1, and you can also try taking log to see you get the better outcome

Comment: and since your data has 1/3 0s. i would see it as a intermittent time series, LSTM might be a good choice, Croston might be another choice for you

Comment: thank you for suggesting Croston. I checked. it can be a good option.